# how to use sysdate command within the SQL like function

Tags: sql, concatenation, sysdate

and (filename like 'DATA%' and filename like '%' + to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') + '%')) this is not working could you please tel me how to include sys date command inside the like

Comment: are you trying to use Like function for Date? if yes, then you can look into an example `SELECT (list of fields) FROM YourTable
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), register_date, 126) LIKE '2009-10-10%'`

Comment: What DBMS is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is for Oracle you can use

```
 (filename LIKE 'DATA%' AND filename LIKE '%' || to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd') || '%')
```